# Backward difference method for approximation of hyperbolic partial-differential equations

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I've a problem even with starting this task:

> Use the backward-difference method to approximate the
>   solutions to the following hyperbolic partial-differential equations
>
> [image: Equation set for the problem]
>
> Use the algorithm with 1. h = 0.1, k = 0.05, 2. h = 0.05, k = 0.1, 3.
>   h = 0.05, k = 0.05. In each case compare your results to the exact solution
>
> ```
> u(x, t) = sin 2πx(cos 2πt + sin 2πt)
> ```
>
> at t = 0.3.

Can someone help me with this backward-difference method, and give a brief explanation of what is going on? This is completely out of my filed of interest, but anyway I have to deal with it ...

Comment: You should move this to computational science.

Comment: Yes this is a math algorithm type question and not a code question.  Also, is this homework?  If you do not have a background in numerical methods this may be fruitless.  First off a backward difference method is a low order method, try using central difference.  And the methods used for discretizing the space domain are usually unstable in the time domain.  I'd recommend looking at Numerical Recipes in C/C++ before trying this.  Even if you don't understand C/C++ you will be able to follow the math in the text and apply it to matlab.